# How to change src attribute of iframe based on <select> value using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a webpage of >20MB (too big) and the problem is that the youtube videos are ~500 KB each! I want to use an HTML5 select option to list 30+ videos. The value is the youtube video ID. User then selects from the dropdown options the desired video. Then the video loads in the iframe.

```
<form>
    <select id="dynamic_select">
        <option value="" selected>Pick a Key and Peele youtube video</option>
        <option value="pSDTmJtE-Bc">Little Homie</option>
        <option value="Dd7FixvoKBw">Substitute Teacher</option>
        <option value="iGAMbNKcN1U">Fronthand Backhand</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

This is the working "template" but I want to replace the "nlD9JYP8u5E" in the src string with the selected option value. Can this be done?

```
<article>
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nlD9JYP8u5E?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0"></iframe>
</article>
```

Comment: You can change it using regex

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: Just html (shown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex in `.replace()` to changing `src` attribute of iframe. In jquery the `.attr()` change attribute of element that i used it in `change` event listener of select element

```
$("#dynamic_select").change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("iframe").attr("src", function(i, a){
        return a.replace(/(?<=embed\/)[^?]+/, val);
    });
});
```

```js
$("#dynamic_select").change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("iframe").attr("src", function(i, a){
        return a.replace(/(?<=embed\/)[^?]+/, val);
    });
    console.log($("iframe").attr("src"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="dynamic_select">
    <option value="" selected>Pick a Key and Peele youtube video</option>
    <option value="pSDTmJtE-Bc">Little Homie</option>
    <option value="Dd7FixvoKBw">Substitute Teacher</option>
    <option value="iGAMbNKcN1U">Fronthand Backhand</option>
  </select>
</form>
<article>
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nlD9JYP8u5E?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0"> 
</iframe>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

add an id to your article (

```
let target=document.getElementById('viewvideo'), myiframe=document.createElement('iframe'); myiframe.src='the url i want to display'; target.innerHTML='';/** empty the previous one then set content with current iframe*/ target.appendChild(myiframe);
```

Of course the string of 'the url i want to display' would be given from the  value like an onChange event.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with JavaScript.

What this script does is call the function `submitted` when the button is clicked, and this function changes the source of the video.

I am not using `<input type="submit">` as this reloads the page and I am not sure how to prevent that.

```
<script>
function submitted(){
    link = document.getElementById("dynamic_select").value;
  document.getElementById("video").src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+link+"?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0";
}
</script>
<form onsubmit="return false;">

<select id="dynamic_select">
<option value="" selected>Pick a Key and Peele youtube video</option>
<option value="pSDTmJtE-Bc">Little Homie</option>
<option value="Dd7FixvoKBw">Substitute Teacher</option>
<option value="iGAMbNKcN1U">Fronthand Backhand</option>
</select>
<button onclick="submitted()">Submit</button>
</form>

<article>

<iframe id="video" class = "youtube" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nlD9JYP8u5E?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0"> 
</iframe>

</article>
```