# In HTMX, how do I request a specific URL for each option within a select form element?

Tags: html, html-select, htmx

I'm using [HTMX](https://htmx.org/) and would like to have a `<select>` form field that automatically loads a specific URL into a `<div>`.

The ["value select" example](https://htmx.org/examples/value-select/) is similar to this idea, but it includes the value as a query parameter such as `/models?make=audi`.  I would like to use a specific URL for each `<option>` instead.

This is an approximation of what I would think *should* work.

```html
<select name="make" hx-target="#models">
  <option hx-get="/models/audi">Audi</option>
  <option hx-get="/models/toyota">Toyota</option>
  <option hx-get="/models/bmw">BMW</option>
</select>

<div id="models">
  <!-- hx-get results would go here -->
</div>
```

However, this does not work and I'm unable to find a way to implement what I describe.  How can I achieve the desired behavior?

**Edit:** [Related Twitter thread](https://mobile.twitter.com/benjaminoakes/status/1406428486378606596)

Comment: I know it's very late, but did you try adding `hx-boost` on the select tag?

Answer (score 15):

I had [a conversation on Twitter](https://mobile.twitter.com/benjaminoakes/status/1406428486378606596) and came to the conclusion that this does not yet exist.

I ended up playing with `htmx:configRequest`, resulting in this reusable JavaScript, which may make sense to contribute back to the HTMX library.

```js
    document.body.addEventListener("htmx:configRequest", function (event) {
      let pathWithParameters = event.detail.path.replace(/:([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/g, function (_match, parameterName) {
        let parameterValue = event.detail.parameters[parameterName]
        delete event.detail.parameters[parameterName]

        return parameterValue
      })

      event.detail.path = pathWithParameters
    })
```

This is an example of how it is used:

```html
    <select name="make" hx-get="/models/:make" hx-target="#models">
      <option name="audi">Audi</option>
      <option name="toyota">Toyota</option>
      <option name="bmw">BMW</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution!

Comment: No problem! I hope to make a PR for HTMX including it sometime soon.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to use parameters in my URL for an HTMX request and this seems like the current way to do it. My regex skills are awful so I'll need a moment for a suggested fix, but if the request URL contains a port value - ie `127.0.0.1:5000` - this tries to parse the port as well and it breaks.

Comment: @BenjaminOakes I might suggest enclosing the param like `<param>` instead of a colon. This follows Flask style params.

Comment: You should be able to do flask params with this regex:  `/<([A-Za-z0-9_]+)>/g` It works really well!  This or something like it should 1,000 percent be in the htmx source.

Answer (score 3):

No scripts needed, just use the [`configRequest`](https://htmx.org/events/#htmx:configRequest) htmx event.

```
<select
  hx-get   =""
  hx-target="#models"
  hx-on    ="htmx:configRequest: event.detail.path = this.value"
>
  <option value="/models/audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="/models/toyota">Toyota</option>
  <option value="/models/bmw">BMW</option>
</select>

<div id="models">
  <!-- hx-get results would go here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Great solution, although there is a new syntax since version `1.9.3` (I cannot edit your answer right now, the queue is full). See also [my answer to another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76837465/how-to-change-hx-get-value-dynamically/78007629#answer-78007629), the [official documentation](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-on#hx-on-recommended) about `hx-on` and the [changelog](https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#193---2023-07-14).

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with some extra help from AlpineJS.

The complexity of this solution is because Chrome-based browsers don't trigger HTMX when the `<select>`'s value changes.

This solution uses Alpine to:

- react to the event (with the `@change` attribute)
- find the `option` element corresponding to the value (using `document.evaluate` and an xPath selector to look for children of the `select` element, `$el`.)
- then trigger HTMX on that element.

```
<select 
  name="make"
  hx-target="#models"
  x-data="{
    renderXPathSelector(value) {return `.//option[contains(., '${value}')]`},
    getChosenOption(value) {return document.evaluate(this.renderXPathSelector(value), $el).iterateNext()},
    tellHTMXOptionChanged(event) { htmx.trigger(this.getChosenOption(event.target.value), 'click')}
  }"
  @change="tellHTMXOptionChanged($event)"
>
  <option hx-get="/models/audi">Audi</option>
  <option hx-get="/models/toyota">Toyota</option>
  <option hx-get="/models/bmw">BMW</option>
</select>
```

If you have `select`s whose values are different than the text, you can use select the `option` in a more simple way:

```js
el.querySelector(`[value="${el.value}"]`)
```

You can support both cases by setting the `chosenOption` function to:

```
const chosenOption = el.querySelector(`[value="${el.value}"]`) ||
                      getChosenOption(event.target.value)
```

---

If you want to use this pattern several times across your app, you can create an "Alpine magic" to simplify the HTML:

```html
<script>
  document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
    Alpine.magic('tellHTMXOptionChanged', (el) => {
      {# This is needed for cross-browser compatability for when a <select> changes #}
      return (event) => {
        function renderXPathSelector(value) {return `.//option[contains(., '${value}')]`}
        function getChosenOption(value) {return document.evaluate(renderXPathSelector(value), el).iterateNext()}
        const chosenOption = el.querySelector(`[value="${el.value}"]`) || getChosenOption(event.target.value)
        htmx.trigger(chosenOption, 'click')
      }
    })
  })
</script>

...

<select 
  name="make"
  hx-target="#models"
  x-data
  @change="$tellHTMXOptionChanged($event)"
>
  <option hx-get="/models/audi">Audi</option>
  <option hx-get="/models/toyota">Toyota</option>
  <option hx-get="/models/bmw">BMW</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question. And the author probably helped in the development of the feature.

But you can find on **htmx** documentation a way to do [Cascading select](https://htmx.org/examples/value-select/)

*Copy/Paste from the doc link :*

```html
<div>
    <label>Make</label>
    <select name="make" hx-get="/models" hx-target="#models" hx-indicator=".htmx-indicator">
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      <option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
      <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Model</label>
    <select id="models" name="model">
      <option value="a1">A1</option>
      ...
    </select>
</div>
```

Has I understand, **htmx** will take `name` attribute from `<select>` and use it in **GET** method to **/models** url and finaly send a request to **/models?make=value_selected**

I hope it will help future people who didn't find the answer elswhere.

Comment: The required url to fetch is of the form `/models/toyota` not `/models?make=toyota` which is why `hx-get` is used in the question and not relying on `name` attribute

Answer (score -2):

You [load the external page into iframe using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52464011/how-to-change-src-attribute-of-iframe-based-on-select-value-using-javascript-j)

Or use Ajax to append the loaded content to the `<div id="models"></div>` based on selected value.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question using HTMX