# How to change hx-get value dynamically?

Tags: django, alpine.js, htmx

I have a button which opens a dialog located in some_template.html:

```
<button @click="open = !open"
        id="btn_id"
        hx-get="/some_url/"
        hx-trigger="click"
        hx-swap="outerHTML">
</button>
```

Then I have `another_template.html` which includes `some_template.html`

In `another_template.html` I am handling a button click:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
        Alpine.data('dialog', () => ({
            handleButtonClick(id) {
                console.log(id); // prints the expected id correctly
                const button = document.getElementById('btn_id');
                const url = `/some_url/${id}`;
                button.setAttribute('hx-get', url);
                console.log(button.attributes); // prints the updated `hx-get` with the id included
                button.click();
            }
        }));
    });
</script>
```

The dialog is opening correctly which means the `button.click()` is working properly.

The main problem is that the `hx-get` in the button is not being updated, i.e., there is no `id` associated with it, and it still processes the request without it, using what was initially defined in the button: `hx-get="/some_url/"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that I was not using [htmx.process()](https://htmx.org/api/#process) after changing the button's attributes. `htmx.process()` forces htmx to reparse the updated DOM.

Comment: Can you show an example of the code? I'm struggling with the same sort of use case. In my case I want to update a button hx-get attribute with a new url with id (Django) so I can retrieve additional formsets (fields). Every time a field is added a counter must go up. On the frontend everything is updated correctly. However, the htmx.process(button) or htmx.process(outer_div_button) do not seem to work. Every time the fields are added the original hx-get url id number is given. In the backend it does not get updated and thus the new fields all get the same id. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Once a node has been processed by htmx, the hx-get attribute is stored internally and changing it in the element won't make a difference, as you've already noticed.

One way to change it is by using the `htmx:configRequest` event. For example:

```
button.addEventListener('htmx:configRequest', (event) => {
   event.detail.path = url;
});
```

You can add the listener to the window and have it check for the presence of a `data-htmx-url` attribute and use that if present, otherwise leave the path untouched. Then in your current code set a `data-htmx-url` attribute on the button with the new url.

```js
window.addEventListener('htmx:configRequest', (event) => {
   if (event.srcElement.getAttribute('data-htmx-url)) {
      event.detail.path = event.srcElement.getAttribute('data-htmx-url);
   }
});
```

Finally, you could combine this with the `htmx:afterRequest` to remove the attribute when the request is done.

```js
window.addEventListener('htmx:afterRequest', (event) => {
   event.detail.elt.removeAttribute('data-htmx-url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do without using an external script:

```html
<button @click="open = !open"
        id="btn_id"
        hx-get="/some_url/"
        hx-trigger="click"
        hx-swap="outerHTML"
        hx-on::config-request="event.detail.path += this.id">
</button>
```

The line that I added basically **updates the path of the request about to be issued**.

Note that this has been tested for the latest release of HTMX (`1.9.10`) but this syntax is relatively new (more info in [the official documentation](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-on#hx-on-recommended) and in the [changelog](https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#193---2023-07-14)).

Also, you don't need the line `hx-trigger="click"` since it's the default behavior for buttons: you may omit it.